# Why can't I reuse a CSS keyframe animation?

Tags: javascript, css, keyframe

I want to have a CSS keyframe animation on submit, every time, but currently it only works the first time. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

CSS:

```
@keyframes enlarge {
0%   {-webkit-transform: scale(1); -ms-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1);}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.5); -ms-transform: scale(1.5); transform: scale(1.5);}
}

.enlarge {
animation-name: enlarge;
animation-duration: 2s;
```

JS:

```
var enlarge = function(response) {

    document.querySelector("#messageContainer").classList.add("enlarge");

    var reset = setTimeout(function() {

        document.querySelector("#messageContainer").classList.remove("enlarge");

    }, 2000);
};
```

I half expected the solution to come to me while I was writing this, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to work as intended given your description... Try clicking the "Run Code Snippet" below:

```js
var enlarge = function(response) {
    document.querySelector("#container").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#example").classList.add("enlarge");
    var reset = setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("#example").classList.remove("enlarge");
        document.querySelector("#container").classList.add("hidden");
    }, 2000);
};
```

```css
#example { 
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
}

@keyframes enlarge {
0%   {-webkit-transform: scale(1); -ms-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1);}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.5); -ms-transform: scale(1.5); transform: scale(1.5);}
}

.hidden { display: none; }

.enlarge {
    animation-name: enlarge;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="hidden">
    <div id="example">My example text</div>
</div>
<button onclick="enlarge()">Submit</button>
```

Are you sure your enlarge function is running on every click of the submit button?

Judging by the fact that your enlarge() function takes a "response" parameter, I'm assuming that you're using it in the response handler of an AJAX request -- does this AJAX request return a non-successful error code if the form has already been submitted once? If this function is attached to the onSuccess() method, that would explain why it is only playing the animation once; the request would only be "succeeding" the first time the button was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I use AJAX, yes, but it doesn't return error in this case. If it returns error a different function will be triggered. I can see that this function (enlarge) is triggered on every submit when I put a console.log in it. I can also see that the adding and removal of the class is working by having a if (...classlist.contains("enlarge")) { {console.log("has"); } and if (!...classlist.contains("enlarge")) { {console.log("has not"); in the function. So everything else seems to be working. It's really strange.

Comment: The code in the OP is a bit simplified. In the real enlarge function there is also a reference to an enclosing div element. The first line in the enlarge function is document.querySelector("#the enclosing div").classList.remove("hidden"); and then, in the setTimeout, I add hidden again so that the enclosing div (together with #messageContainer that is inside) gets hidden. I have now realized that if I remove these actions and have everyting visible all the time the animation works properly. But why that is I have no idea. And I really need to hide it somehow.

Comment: This is the real code:

var enlarge = function(response) {

document.querySelector("#enclosingdiv").classList.remove("hidden");

    document.querySelector("#example").classList.add("enlarge");

    var reset = setTimeout(function() {

        document.querySelector("#example").classList.remove("enlarge");

document.querySelector("#enclosingdiv").classList.add("hidden");

    }, 2000);
};

Comment: @Candleout I edited my code snippet above to add the hidden container you mentioned (I tried both display:none and visibility:hidden). After testing on FF, Edge, and Chrome, it still appears to work... Make sure that things are in the order you stated in this post -- if you try to add the animation before removing the hidden class, the animation will be optimized away.

Comment: I will come back to this part after everything else is done ... I'll post here when I know how it went. Thanks for the help!